# Sudden fan noises Ubuntu 18.04 LTS XPS 13 7390

Tags: 18.04, drivers, dell, fan

My XPS 13 7390 was working completely fine but all of a sudden its fan started making noises like a generator When we bought this, we bought a windows machine too, on which the fan did something similar and get fixed by changing/updating Wireless Driver. But I am not sure this is the case in Ubuntu machine.

A week ago everything was fine but now, Its sometimes get starts like a generator and make annoying noises and then stop. I even have to install i8ktc fan utilities to stop it, when I am fed up from the noise.

out of my commands are `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280`

```
junaid@junaid-XPS-13-7390:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1653]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

also when I do `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`

```
junaid@junaid-XPS-13-7390:~$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    5.768779] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    5.768781] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:7906:7773a757
[    5.890452] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.919357] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
[    5.919414] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.919530] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.919554] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.922551] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    5.922558] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.922560] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    5.922985] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.026549] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX1650w 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (200D2W), REV=0x340
[    6.039058] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    6.039501] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    6.203112] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 4c:1d:96:da:60:24
[    6.312617] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    6.333044] Modules linked in: fjes(-) arc4 dell_laptop(+) intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_intel(+) kvm_intel snd_hda_codec kvm snd_hda_core irqbypass snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel iwlmvm(OE) pcbc snd_pcm mac80211(OE) snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event aesni_intel aes_x86_64 snd_rawmidi crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd dell_wmi intel_cstate dell_smbios dcdbas snd_seq intel_rapl_perf input_leds iwlwifi(OE) snd_seq_device joydev serio_raw snd_timer intel_wmi_thunderbolt idma64 virt_dma wmi_bmof dell_wmi_descriptor snd cfg80211(OE) soundcore rtsx_pci_ms intel_lpss_pci(+) memstick compat(OE) intel_lpss ucsi_acpi processor_thermal_device intel_soc_dts_iosf typec_ucsi typec int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone mac_hid acpi_pad int3400_thermal intel_hid
[    8.329267] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.492548] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[ 9503.350077] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[ 9503.513242] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[13970.348388] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[13970.511953] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

I am not sure what those errors are. but right now

[image]

and mostly its fan2. which gives red signals and make a lot of noise but like generator, its start, take a pace and then make a shouting sound and stop. this can be fixable through software changes or I need to get it repalced?

UPDATED

[image]

Comment: Fan broken. fan2 has even less RPM than fan1 and is louder. And it started suddenly. Clear signs of a broken or dirty fan. If cleaning doesn't help, replace it.

Comment: Use `top` to see if and which processes are using a lot of CPU when you observe the issue. Could be kworker.